# How do create a view of active companies by month?

Tags: mysql, sql

My Table looks like this:

```
Company Date    Status
-------------------------------------
ABC     1-Jan-19    Event
ABC     1-Feb-19    Event
ABC     1-Jan-19    Event
ABC     1-Feb-19    Event
DEF     1-Feb-19    Event
DEF     1-Mar-19    Event
DEF     1-Feb-19    Event
DEF     1-Mar-19    Event
GHI     1-Mar-19    Event
GHI     1-Mar-19    Event
JKL     1-Jan-19    Event
JKL     1-Feb-19    Event
JKL     1-Feb-19    Event
JKL     1-Mar-19    Event
```

I am trying to find out how many active companies I have in each month.  An active company is categorized by having at least one event during that month.

See the table below of the data above.  I am only looking for the end results of Month and Active Companies for that month.

```
           Jan  Feb Mar
    ABC     2   2       
    DEF         2   2
    GHI             2
    JKL     1   2   1
    -------------------
    Active  2   3   3
```

This, of course, would be a view.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `date` column, is it a `date` or `datetime` column, or a `varchar'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation to pivot the data and `WITH ROLLUP` to generate the summary record:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT
    company,
    SUM(YEAR(my_date) = 2019 AND MONTH(my_date) = 1 AND status = 'Event') Jan,
    SUM(YEAR(my_date) = 2019 AND MONTH(my_date) = 2 AND status = 'Event') Feb,
    SUM(YEAR(my_date) = 2019 AND MONTH(my_date) = 3 AND status = 'Event') Mar
FROM my_table
GROUP BY company WITH ROLLUP;
```

Notes:

- this assumes that `date` is of a date-like datatype
- it is always a good idea to include the `YEAR()` in the conditions; enventually, your data might spread overall several years
- `date` is not a good pick for a column name, since it clashes with a reserved word; I renamed it to `my_date`

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic is:

```
SELECT company,
       SUM(MONTH(my_date) = 1) as Jan,
       SUM(MONTH(my_date) = 2) as Feb,
       SUM(MONTH(my_date) = 3) as Mar
FROM my_table
WHERE status = 'Event' AND my_date >= '2019-01-01' AND
      my_date < '2020-10-01'
GROUP BY company;
```

However, you cannot use `rollup` with this -- unless you want the event sum.  Instead:

```
(SELECT company,
        SUM(MONTH(my_date) = 1) as Jan,
        SUM(MONTH(my_date) = 2) as Feb,
        SUM(MONTH(my_date) = 3) as Mar
 FROM my_table
 WHERE status = 'Event' AND my_date >= '2019-01-01' AND
       my_date < '2020-10-01'
 GROUP BY company
) UNION ALL
(SELECT 'Total',
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(my_date) = 1 THEN company END) as Jan,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(my_date) = 2 THEN company END) as Feb,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN MONTH(my_date) = 3 THEN company END) as Mar
FROM my_table
WHERE status = 'Event' AND my_date >= '2019-01-01' AND
      my_date < '2020-10-01'
);
```